# MVC - Partial View Update after .ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial

I have a page with a number of tables, each of which is in a partial view. I want to be able to enter some from/to dates for one of these tables, get the new data, and ONLY update that table.

Fragment from my view:

```
               <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    var a = item.accounts;
                    foreach (var item2 in a)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", @item2.TradeDate)</td>
                            <td>@item2.AccountName</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>@String.Format("{0:n}", item2.ExecutionPrice)</td>
                            <td>@String.Format("{0:n}", item2.PrincipalAmount)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
```

What I want to do is get the html created by this and update a div with the new table.

When the app first loads, I have a method returning an ActionResult for this partial. After this, the user will set the new dates and click Go, after which I make an ajax call. This is the point at which I want to just update that table.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I've made some changes. I now have this ajax call:

```
         var url = "Company/Transactions?symbol=" + $("#savesymbol").val() + "&fromDate=" + $("#fromDate").val() + "&toDate=" + $("#toDate").val();
     alert(url)
     $.ajax({
         url: url, 
         type: "Post",
         //dataType: "html",
         async: false,
         success: function (result) {
             $('.transTarget').html(result);              
         },
         error: function () {
             alert("Error occured");
         }
     });
```

This results in the whole page being placed in my .transTarget div, instead of just the partial. But since Company/Transaction returns a partial view, why do I get the whole page?

This is the Company/Transaction method in my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Transactions(string symbol, string fromDate, string toDate)
{

string url = ServiceUrl + "api/company/transactions/" + symbol + "/" + fromDate + "/" + toDate + "/";


Transaction transactionInfo = new Transaction();
List<Transaction> transactionsList = new List<Models.Transaction>();

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var transactions = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var parsedTransactions = JObject.Parse(transactions)["Table1"];
    foreach (dynamic item in parsedTransactions)
    {
        Transaction.Accounts a = new Transaction.Accounts();

        a.AccountId = item.account_id;
        a.AccountName = item.AccountName;


        transactionInfo.accounts.Add(a);
    }

    transactionsList.Add(transactionInfo);

    return PartialView("_transactions", transactionsList);
}
return PartialView("Error");
}
```

EDIT:

This is what triggers it:

```
                var a = item.dates;
            <div>
                From:
                <input id="fromDate" type="date" name="fromDate" value="@a.FromDate">
                To:
                <input id="toDate" type="date"  value="@a.ToDate">
                <button type="button" id="btn_transactions" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: How are you triggering that ajax call? (your description suggest you have a submit button and its making a normal submit - and your script is not being executed, or both are)

Comment: Triggered by a datepicker input. The script is definitely being called, because I see the result with the new dates.

Comment: See last edit for this.

Comment: I got it working, thanks to an idea you "triggered". I was previously setting the html of the div with the table, instead of the whole page. Thanks!